# ¿Por qué antes "lector" se decía "letor"?

Tags: historia

De acuerdo al DLE, la palabra lector viene del latin lector:

> [**lector, ra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=N3RPAwo)
>
> Del lat.
>
> *lector, -ōris.*
>
> 1. adj. Que lee o tiene el hábito de leer.

Sin embargo, en algún momento del español, la palabra usada fue "letor":

> No con poco miedo me he atrevido, discretísimo letor, a sacar a luz esta pequeña obra, siendo como soy en edad tan mozo, en ciencia tan falto y en experiencia tan corto.
>
> *El viaje entretenido, Agustín de Rojas Villadrando, 1603*
>
> Y si pareciere al letor imposible haber tiempo en lo que sobra del estudio para tantos artes, ni en una vida entera de cien años, digo que dió nuestro Señor al Venturoso tanto entendimiento, que las cosas que en otros fueran menester años para saberlas, en él bastaban días; y en oficios mecánicos y de agricoltura, bastábale una sola vista
>
> *Caballero venturoso, Juan Valladares de Valdelomar, 1617*
>
> ¡Quién te podría, letor, manifestar el alegría que don Polindo sintía en su coraçón con tan dulce razonar e piadosa y alegre respuesta!
>
> *Polindo, Anónimo, 1526*

Si la palabra en latín ya tenía la combinación de letras "ct", ¿cómo fue que evolucionó a "letor" y en algún momento de nuevo a "lector"?

Comment: Puedes echarle un vistazo a este artículo: https://www.delcastellano.com/setiembre-otubre/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La combinación *-ct-* parece haberles costado algo a los hablantes neolatines.

En la evolución más típica, el grupo *-ct-* en castellano llegó a ser *-ch-*, evidente en palabras como *leche*, *pecho* u *ocho*.

Pero la «solución» para facilitar la pronunciación no era solo esa.  En el galaicoportugués, francés y aragonés, el grupo se convirtió en *-it-*, y en el portugués, especialmente el dialecto brasileño, sufrió una segunda transformación para las combinaciones que quedaban en que simplemente se suprimió la *c*.  En el leonés, además de la solución galaicoportuguesa (en los dialectos occidentales), la solución variaba entre lo del castellano *-ch-* y de convertirlo en *-ut-* (dialectos centrales y orientales).  En catalán, la solución era simplemente suprimir la *-c-*, a veces modificando la vocal anterior a la vez o convirtiendo el grupo en *-lt-*.  En todos los idiomas, algunos cultismos mantuvieron la combinación culta.

¿Por qué menciono todo lo de arriba?  Pues porque creo que debe ser evidente que había mucha variación temprano en el idioma.  En el castellano, tenemos restos de todas estas transformaciones.  Aparte de la forma estándar *-ch-*, con la vocalización de *c* en *i* tenemos *deleitar* y *pleita*, y en *u* tenemos *auto (de fe)* y *pauta*, quitando la *c* tenemos *adjetivo*, y manteniendo el grupo como en *efecto* o *lector*, etc.  Sin duda, si buscásemos lo suficiente, podríamos encontrar ejemplos de aquellas palabras con otras transformaciones.

Por eso, no debe sorprender que se usase alguna u otra vez *letor* o incluso *leitor* o *leutor* especialmente según la zona del hablante y que esas formas convivieron.  Tras el tiempo, con la estandarización de la forma escrita (quién sabe de la hablada), ciertas formas ganaron y de ahí solo encontramos *lector*.  Pero **no era, pues, cuestión de ir de *-ct-*, transformarse en *-t-* y volverse a *-ct-*,<sup>1</sup> sino de coexistir varias formas y ganar una de ellas al final.**

---

<sup>1. Ejemplos existen de algo así, pero se tratan de una transformación y reimportación, como en *local* → *lugar* → *local*.</sup>

Comment: Yo no sé vosotros, pero yo cada vez que leo una respuesta del gran @guifa sufro un orgasmo mental.